# Dynamic get nested list according to index

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say we have 2 lists, one is nested lists, like:

```
a = [[[['test'],['test1']], ['test2']], ['test3', 'test4']]
```

the other one stores **index**:

```
b = [0,1,0]
```

so we can retrive `test2` with:

```
a[0][1][0]
```

I am wondering is there any convenient way to retrive value from nested list according to **index** list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
a = [[[["test"], ["test1"]], ["test2"]], ["test3", "test4"]]
b = [0, 1, 0]

item = a
for i in b:
    item = item[i]
print(item) # test2
```

Comment: wow, this is a very clearly solution.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case for some functional programming and the reduce method:

```
from functools import reduce

a = [[[['test'],['test1']], ['test2']], ['test3', 'test4']]
b = [0,1,0]

print(reduce(lambda array, index : array[index], b, a))

# Make it into a re-useable function:
follow_array = lambda nested, indices : reduce(lambda array, index : array[index], indices, nested)
print(follow_array(a, b))
```

The nested list is used as the initializer for the reduce function which then reduces over the array of indices finding going level by level till it finds the result. The inner `lambda` function used by reduce takes the next indice and pulls out the array at that nesting level when is used as input for the next iteration of reduce.